# How to deal with left employee in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-administration

I am new to SharePoint, I have gone through the article of Microsoft for removing the user from SharePoint (Remove license, delete user from O365 users).

[Delete a user from your organization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/delete-a-user?view=o365-worldwide)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/remove-users

I want to know what if the user who left the organization was added into 50 different Sharepoint groups of different sites.

what should be the process to remove such user from all groups from all site (also share if any precaution needs to be taken before doing that)

I just want to define one process to deal with such scenario.

Looking forward for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell command to remove users from all SharePoint groups:

```
$users=("user1@mycompany.com", "user2 @mycompany.com")
$site=https://MyCompany.Sharepoint.com/sites/site1
$groups=Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $site
foreach($user in $users) { foreach ($group in $groups){Remove-SPOUser -Site $site -LoginName $user -Group $group.LoginName}}
```

You can change the $site parameter with your sites. More information: [SharePoint Online: Remove users from site groups using PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37480.sharepoint-online-remove-users-from-site-groups-using-powershell.aspx)